# Filter values from a scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to filter values smaller than 10 from a huge (1Mx1M) CSR matrix (SciPy). 
Since all my values are integers, dividing by 10 and remultiplying by 10 does the job, but I was wondering if there isn't a better way to go about filtering elements.

**EDIT:**
The answer below works. Check that you have the latest version of SciPy.

Comment: How does that work? 11 / 10 * 10 = 10, not 11.

Comment: Well, for my specific application it's good enough, but like I said, there should be a better (i.e. faster and more accurate) way of doing it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also go with the less hacky, but probably slower:

```
m = m.multiply(m >= 10)
```

To understand what's going on:

```
>>> m = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((1000, 1000), dtype=np.int)
>>> m[np.random.randint(0, 1000, 20),
      np.random.randint(0, 1000, 20)] = np.random.randint(0, 100, 20)
>>> m.data
array([92, 46, 99, 24, 75, 16, 49, 60, 87, 64, 91, 37, 30, 32, 25, 40, 99,
        9,  3, 84])
>>> m >= 10
<1000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.bool_'>'
    with 18 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> m = m.multiply(m >= 10)
>>> m
<1000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 18 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> m.data
array([92, 46, 99, 24, 75, 16, 49, 60, 87, 64, 91, 37, 30, 32, 25, 40, 99,
       84])
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's fair to call direct manipulation of the compressed representation "hacky" — the representation is [documented](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html), after all.

Comment: Please, don't get me wrong, I think your answer is perfectly valid. Your current single upvote is mine. ;) And I have answers about sparse matrices that go into terrible complications with all three internal arrays. Such hacky manipulations are justified because `scipy.sparse` is very much in the making, and with every release there are huge functionality leaps. But while we are not there yet, eventually the objective should be for it to be possible to do `m[m < 10] = 0`, as one would do with any array, and be done with it. My answer is a bit closer to that ideal, I think.

Comment: Thanks Jaime! Is interpreting (m >= 10) as a matrix a new feature? It doesn't seem to work in my version of SciPy.

Comment: @Omer I had to upgrade Scipy from 0.10 to 0.13 to make it work

Comment: what would be the hacky but faster version?

Comment: @GarethRees had a now deleted answer that did something like: `m.data[m.data < 10] = 0; m.eliminate_zeros()`

Answer (score 2):

I think the version issue has to do with the implementation of the comparison operators.  `m >= 0`, uses a `m.__gt__`.  (I don't have an earlier version of `scipy` to test this, but I believe there is one or more SO threads on the topic).

Something which might work in earlier version is:

```
m.data *= m.data>=10
m.eliminate_zeros()
```

In other words use a standard `numpy` operation to set selected values to 0.  The test could be a lot more complicated.  And then use a standard `sparse` function to clean it up.  When you say, 'filter' that's essentially what you want to do, isn't it: set some values to zero and remove them from the sparse matrix?